# Motivation behind tensor product construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

At the beginning of Dummit and Foote section 10.4, in order to extend a $R$ module $N$ to an $S$ module, where $R$ is a subring of $S$, we start with the most general setting where this is possible: a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module on the product $S \times N$. Then, we take the quotient of this group by subgroup generated by elements of the form
$$
(s_1+s_2, n) - (s_1,n)-(s_2,n),\\
(s,n_1+n_2)-(s,n_1)-(s,n_2),\\
(sr,n) - (s,rn),
$$
where $s,s_1,s_2 \in S, r \in R, n,n_1,n_2 \in N$. My question is why in the third kind of elements we are restricting ourselves to elements of the form $sr$ with $s \in S$ and $r \in R$ only. For $s_1, s_2 \in S$ and $n \in N$, we also have (after the construction has completed) that $(s_1s_2)n = s_1(s_2n)$. Why not consider these elements in the quotienting process?

Comment: Sorry, what elements of the free $\Bbb Z$-module on $S\times N$ are you suggesting we consider? Please be explicit. If you are talking about $(s_1s_2,n)-(s_1,s_2n)$, that doesn't make sense because $s_2n$ is not defined.

Comment: @coiso I meant the type of elements you mentioned. I understand that $s_2n$ is yet not defined, but on the other hand, the third type of elements that are considered contains terms of the form $(sr,n)$. Here $sr$ might be in $S$ and not in $R$. What is the difference?

Comment: $sr$ is defined and $sn$ isn't.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Thanks!